# Javascript counter for each call method

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Hello i'm trying to create a counter in javascript which counts the time since I entered a function but got a problem.

I'm using socket.io and i would like to know the time since someone is disconnect

I tried this :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        seconds = 0;
        function incrementSeconds() {
         seconds += 1;
         console.log(seconds); 
}
setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);
 });
});
```

The counter works bad because the variable seconds is incremented more and more quickly every time we return to the disconnected function.
I even have the impression that if the person has been offline for 6 seconds, when we return to the function, the second attribute will go 6 seconds faster ...

Thanks for help

Comment: better keep the disconnection time in DBwherever you are keeping the data for each socket

Comment: Thanks for you answer, how can it resolve my problem??

Comment: You could save all the disconnect times in a map or an object. You could add a global object like `socketDisconnectDate = {}`. On disconnect you could set the time correctly: `socket.on('disconnect', function() { socketDisconnectDate[socket.id] = (new Date()).getTime() });`. You would be able to retrieve the time since the disconnect using `(socketDisconnectDate[socket.id] - (new Date()).getTime())` (ms since disconnect). As Be Weria pointed out you could save this to a db for persistence.

Comment: Where do i put this code ? "(socketDisconnectDate[socket.id] - (new Date()).getTime())"